# Extract python 'native' values from numpy structured array

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

I have a structured numpy array.

The numpy structure matches the type `google.protobuf.Timestamp`.

I need to extract the `seconds` `int64` and the `nanos` `int32` from each element of said structure and assign it to the **real** `Timestamp` structure.

Below I list a script that does just that in a convenient way for anyone to test (`numpy` and `protobuf` Python modules need to be installed).

How do I get rid/circumvent the `TypeError` listed at the end and have the values out of the numpy structure in the `Timestamp` variable?

```py
import numpy as np
from google.protobuf import timestamp_pb2

# numpy structure that mimics google.protobuf.Timestamp
Timestamp_t = np.dtype([('seconds', np.int64), ('nanos', np.int32)])

# populate numpy array with above structure
x_values_size = 3
x_values = np.empty((x_values_size,), dtype=Timestamp_t)
x_values['seconds'] = np.linspace(0, 100, num=x_values_size, dtype=np.int64)
x_values['nanos']   = np.linspace(0, 10, num=x_values_size, dtype=np.int32)

# copy data from numpy structured array to a descriptor-created Timestamp
for elem in np.nditer(x_values) :
    # destination protobuf structure (actually, part of some sequence)
    # try 1: this will actually change the type of 'ts'
    ts1 = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
    print(type(ts1)) # Timestamp as expected
    ts1 = elem
    print(ts1) # now a numpy.ndarray
    print(type(ts1))
    print(ts1.dtype)

    # try 2: assign member by member
    ts2 = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
    # fails with:
    # TypeError: array(0, dtype=int64) has type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, but expected one of: (<class 'int'>,)
    ts2.seconds = elem['seconds']
    ts2.nanos = elem['nanos']
    print("-----")
```

Disclaimer: hardcore newbie when it comes to python and numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So

```
In [112]: x_values
Out[112]: 
array([(  0,  0), ( 50,  5), (100, 10)], 
      dtype=[('seconds', '<i8'), ('nanos', '<i4')])
```

I don't usually recommend using `nditer` unless you need special behavior.  Simple iteration on the array (rows if 2d) is usually all you need.  But to better understand what is happening, lets compare the iteration methods:

```
In [114]: for elem in np.nditer(x_values):
     ...:     print(elem, elem.dtype)
     ...:     print(type(elem))   
(0, 0) [('seconds', '<i8'), ('nanos', '<i4')]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(50, 5) [('seconds', '<i8'), ('nanos', '<i4')]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(100, 10) [('seconds', '<i8'), ('nanos', '<i4')]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

In [115]: for elem in x_values:
     ...:     print(elem, elem.dtype)
     ...:     print(type(elem))
(0, 0) [('seconds', '<i8'), ('nanos', '<i4')]
<class 'numpy.void'>
(50, 5) [('seconds', '<i8'), ('nanos', '<i4')]
<class 'numpy.void'>
(100, 10) [('seconds', '<i8'), ('nanos', '<i4')]
<class 'numpy.void'>
```

Same except the `type` is different, `np.ndarray` v. `np.void`.  It's easier to modify the `nditer` variable.

Do the same but looking at one field:

```
In [119]: for elem in np.nditer(x_values):
     ...:     print(elem['seconds'], type(elem['seconds']))   
0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
50 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
100 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

In [120]: for elem in x_values:
     ...:     print(elem['seconds'], type(elem['seconds']))
0 <class 'numpy.int64'>
50 <class 'numpy.int64'>
100 <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

I don't have the `protobuf` code, but I suspect

```
ts2.seconds = elem['seconds']
```

will work better with the 2nd iteration, the one that produces `np.int64` values.  Or add `elem['seconds'].item()`.

Comment: So, the short version of the answer is to add `.item()` when assigning the values. I timed the two iteration methods and the `np.nditer` is a tad faster, even with the additional `.item()` call. I guess I have to do with assigning memberwise from one structure to the other. Thanks.