# NumPy: iterate over outer dimension of numpy array using nditer

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am unable to iterate over the outer axis of a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(2*3).reshape(2,3)
it = np.nditer(a)
for i in it:
    print i
```

and this gives, as one would expect:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I would, however, like the output to come in threes, such that I have iterated over the outer axes:

```
(0, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
```

I know of many ways in which I can achieve this, but after pouring over the [nditer documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html), I can't seem to find a solution using nditer. I am using this as an opportunity to learn nditer. So I would prefer not using other solutions, unless it is genuinely more efficient or pythonic.

Comment: Try commenting the `it = np.nditer(a)` line

Comment: I'm using this as an example to learn nditer. I know that I can iterate through the outer dimension using "for i in a:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to control the iteration with a plain `for`:

```
In [17]: a
Out[17]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [18]: for row in a:
    ...:     print(row)
    ...:     
[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
```

Doing this with `nditer` is just plain awkward.  Unless you need broadcasting use `cython` as described at the end of the page, `nditer` does not offer any speed advantages.  Even with `cython`, I've gotten better speeds with `memoryviews` than with `nditer`.

Look at `np.ndindex`.  It creates a dummy array with reduced dimensions, and does a nditer on that:

```
In [20]: for i in np.ndindex(a.shape[0]):
    ...:     print(a[i,:])
    ...:     
[[0 1 2]]
[[3 4 5]]
```

Got it:

```
In [31]: for x in np.nditer(a.T.copy(), flags=['external_loop'], order='F'):
    ...:     print(x)

[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
```

Like I said - awkward

I recently explored the difference between direct iteration and nditer over a 1d structured array:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43005985/901925

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted to know. I was mistakenly under the impression that nditer would give me a speed advantage. And yes, this is awkward and unnecessary. Duly noted! thank you @hpaulj

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate it over just like you iterate over a 1D array to get the output like you want.

```
 for k,v in enumerate(a):
      print(v)
```

Comment: thanks! As I said, I know of many ways of doing this, including this. In your answer, you can even get rid of enumerate, to get the same result. I'm looking for answers that uses nditer.

Comment: as it is mentioned in numpy nditer docs that  "nditer supersedes flatiter. " https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatiter.html#numpy.flatiter

Comment: can you please describe what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to achieve what your solution would give. But I am trying to learn nditer, so I am looking for a solution that would use nditer. I don't understand what your point is by mentioning: "nditer supersedes flatiter.". I know this, and I'm trying to use this fact to make a generator that only spits out the outer axis, and not every element in the array.